# What is the Space Complexity of following function and how?

Tags: recursion, big-o, space-complexity

Consider following recursive function.

```
int f(int n){
   if(n<=0) return 1; return f(n-1)+f(n-1);
}
```

It is said that though there are `2^N` (2 powered to N) calls but only `N` calls exist at a given time. Can someone explain how?

Comment: But just for the sake of completeness: Space complexity of the described algorithm is still O(N^2), not O(N)

Comment: Is it because memory from left recursive calls may not have been cleaned when right recursive calls occupy space or is there any other explanation?

Comment: It is because your return value is growing with 2^N. To store this value, you need at least O(N) of space. And since you need to store O(N) values of it, the total complexity is O(N^2).

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  The complexity part is in the *else* portion:

```
return f(n-1)+f(n-1)
```

This spawns two calls at **n-1** for each call at **n**.  However, note the order of evaluation:

```
call f(n-1) ... left side
save the value as temp1
call f(n-1) ... right side
add the value to temp1
return that value
```

The entire left-side call tree has to complete before the right-side call tree can begin -- and that happens at *every* depth level.  For each value of **n**, there will be only one call active at any point in time.  For instance, f(2) gives us a sequence like this:

```
call f(2)
n isn't <= 0 ...
    call f(1) ... left
    n isn't <= 0 ...
        call f(0) ... left | left
        n <= 0; return 1
        save the 1
        call f(0) ... left | right
        n <=0; return 1
        add the 1 to the temp value;
        return 2
    save the 2
    call f(1) ... right
        call f(0) ... left | left
        n <= 0; return 1
        save the 1
        call f(0) ... left | right
        n <=0; return 1
        add the 1 to the temp value;
        return 2
    add this 2 to the temp value, making 4
    return the 4
done ...
```

At each point, there are no more than n+1 calls active (see indentation level), although we eventually execute 2^(n+1)-1 calls.  We're off by one (n+1 instead of n) because we terminate at 0 instead of 1.

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Perfect Explanation. Thanks. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  @javad did a nice job, too.  Remember to "accept" an answer (eventually) so StackOverflow can retire it gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

For each `n`, `f(n-1)` is called twice. So if you draw a tree with `n` at root and add a branch for each call to `f(n-1)` and so on, you will see that you have a full binary tree of height `n`, which has 2^n nodes (total number of calls). 
But it is important to note that the second call to `f(n-1)` cannot be initiated without first completing the first call and returning the result. The same holds recursively for `f(n-2)` calls inside `f(n-1)`, ... .

The worst case (I assume that is what you are looking for), happens when the set of your function calls reach `f(0)` and you are at one of the leaves of the call tree. What you have in your call stack is a set of function calls starting from `f(n-1)`, `f(n-2)`, ... , `f(1)`, `f(0)`. So at each point of time you have at most O(n) functions in your stack. (Which is equal to the height of the call tree).

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Appreciate the effort.